# How to reference the same CodeBehind class from multiple .aspx files (and be able to pre-compile the website)?

Tags: asp.net-2.0, code-behind, web-deployment-project

I have a set of aspx pages that each live in their own directory and reference a single aspx.cs code behind file.

This has worked fine previously because I never tried to pre-compile the site. IIS must have individually compiled each aspx, linking them to the contents of App_Code but never referencing more than one aspx at a time.

Now that I'm trying to pre-compile the website using Web Deployment Projects I keep getting errors about the same class being found in multiple assemblies.

I can't just drop the aspx.cs in App_Code and subclass it because it wouldn't be able to find the controls on the .aspx pages when compiling. Maybe I could explicitly define every control on the page in the .cs? But would that allow them to be wired up correctly?

Any other ideas on how I can reference the same Page class from multiple .aspx pages and be able to pre-compile the entire website?

**Edit:**
It looks like CodeFileBaseClass may be what I want. I'll drop my .cs in App_Code, explicitly define all my pages controls, then specify this classs as CodeFileBaseClass in the aspx files that inherit from it. Thoughts?

**Edit2:**
I came up with a solution, but since I can't yet mark it as accepted, I'd still like to see if anyone else could come up with some other solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to:

1. Take my .aspx.cs and copy it into App_Code with a new class name (`FooPage`)
2. Modify `FooPage` to explicitly declare all server side controls it references.
3. Now for each of my .aspx files that referenced the original .aspx.cs:

   1. Create an .aspx.cs file for them.
   2. The class in the .aspx.cs will inherit from the class I moved into App_Code
   3. Set `CodeFileBaseClass="Namespace.To.FooPage"` in the .aspx

This allows ASP.net to easily wire up all the server side controls in the .aspx to the protected members of the base class.

Now I only have 1 of each class in my code and can pre-compile the entire site!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to be able to perform pre-compilation with this framework.

You may want to build a user control that performs the function you need and then you can have include it on the individual pages as needed.

Comment: The problem with making it a user control is that the whole point is that each .aspx file is unique in that the layout of everything on the page is different. Obviously if this wasn't a legacy site I would have designed it differently, but even then some of the differences between the .aspx pages would have to be more than just CSS. Some are changes to clean up the Viewstate.